# Make ListBox items aprear one by one in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am having a collection bound to a WPF ListBox, I want to make the listboxItems aprear one after the other one first binding to the data. To have an effect similar to powerPoint one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options spring to mind:

A. create a storyboard that animates opacity, and apply it to the `ItemTemplate`
 B. use a timer on a background thread to add items one-by-one to the bound collection

Comment: I have thought of that but the use of timer will be kinda CPU consuming especially if I have a lot of data.

Comment: Timer is not very CPU intensive at all.

Comment: How about the idea of changing the template of the ListBow to be a canvas and then translate the elements to their position?

Comment: I tried it it was ok, only a note for people who want to do it, use DispatcherTimer it is better.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use a timer and add the items to the collection one by one, raising a property changed event in between?

Comment: But shuldn't be time consuming? I am thinking of changing the template of the ListBox to make it a Canvas and then give each Item a position and then animate a transition from the point (0,0) to the actual position but I don't see how to implement it.